# Can the square of a P.D.F. not be a PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say you have a valid density function $f(x)$ from $[0, 1]$. Is there a function $f(x)$ such that $cf^2(x)$ is not a valid density function $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}$?

My understanding that a P.D.F. will be invalid if any of the following conditions are not met

1. There is not an asymptote in its domain
2. There are no negative values
3. The integral equals 1.

If the first condition is met, then $\int_0^1 cf^2(x)$ will be some real value $b$, so chose $c=\frac{1}{b}$. Thus the third condition will be met.

Additionally an asymptote cannot be moved by squaring a function. Thus the first condition will never be an asymptote in the domain of $cf^2(x)$ if there is not one in $f(x)$. Which there cannot be, as $f(x)$ is a valid density function.

Finally, it is impossible to get a negative value from a square, therefore condition 2 will always be met for $cf^2(x)$.

Thus there is no such valid density function $f(x)$ where $cf^2(x)$ is not also a valid density function. However I know this is incorrect as this is from a question that states that there is such a function. Where am I wrong and what is a counter-example to this?

Comment: Hint: think about the function $1/\sqrt{x}$

Comment: If $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, for a *unique* $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have that $c f(x)^2$ is a PDF. On the other hand $f>0$ and $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ do not ensure $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$: just consider $f(x)=\frac{e^{-|x|}}{2\sqrt{\pi|x|}}$, for instance.

Comment: Both counterexamples for $f(x)$ listed above are not valid pdfs themselves as they contain asymptotes on $0$ though?

Comment: To be bounded is not necessary to be a PDF: consider the PDF of a squared uniform distribution. And if $f(x)$ is non-negative and bounded on $[0,1]$, it is trivial that the same applies to $f(x)^2$.